# Removing an Onclick Event From a Menu Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a AJAX search plugin for Wordpress that displays in my mobile menu by targeting a specific menu ID (`menu-item-6101`). Everything works great, but when I click on it the menu is dismissed (which prevents you from doing any searches, the expected behaviour is for the menu to stay visible while typing).

I have spent a number of hours researching, and it seems that there is an `onclick` event attached to the `<a>` of that menu item that is likely causing the menu to be dismissed (note that none of the other `parent -> child` toggles cause this, only this menu item that the search plugin is using to display a search box).

I have tried every single variation of `event.preventDefault();`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` & `event.stopPropagation();`, as well as trying to remove the listener, send it to null, etc. but unfortunately I am having issues with either the targeting (e.g. fetching the ID, and then targeting the `<a>`, or it is being overridden due to the javascript load order.

I have also tried to make an `onclick` event for that menu item div that forces the mobile menu to stay visible (the menu gets `style="display:none;"` added to when when focus is changed), so I thought perhaps that would be a different approach:

```
jQuery('div.proinput').click(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('#mobile_menu');
    element.style.removeProperty("display");
    jQuery('.et_mobile_menu').css({
      display: inline-block !important;
    });
  });
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is:

```
jQuery(".et_mobile_menu .menu-item a").not(".toggle-menu").off("click");
```

Hope that this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the menu toggle is actually being fired by the `div#ajaxsearchpro3_2` inside de anchor. Try with this (assuming the div will allways have the same ID):

**FIXED**

```
document.getElementById('ajaxsearchpro3_2')
    .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: I have added that code, and noted that it did add it to ajaxsearchpro3_2. However, the menu is still dismissed when I click in the search box. I have left the code in place if you want to take a look, thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the parentheses in the stopPropagation() method. Now it's fixed, try again.

Comment: Is the code inside a document ready event? If you paste the code in the console it works, so it looks like you need to add the listener after it propagates to the anchor.